# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function processGalleryConfig() on null

Tags: wysiwyg, magento2.3.5

I have upgraded my Magento 2.2.8 website to 2.3.5. The system used the Ves theme. But currently, the Ves theme doesn't have the latest theme module for Magento 2.3.5. Ves theme used landcooder page builder and Megamenu. so I have directly purchased the module and integrated it into my system. After compilation. Admin megamenu edit page shows an error of

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function processGalleryConfig() on null : vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Config.php:209
```

From my findings, I have added below code on mega menu di.xml file

```
<type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\CompositeConfigProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="variablePluginConfigProvider" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Magento\Variable\Model\Variable\ConfigProvider</item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="widgetPluginConfigProvider" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Magento\Widget\Model\Widget\Config</item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="wysiwygConfigPostProcessor" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\DefaultConfigProvider</item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="galleryConfigProvider" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Gallery\DefaultConfigProvider</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

But same issue exist. so could please help me to sort out this issue.